# Updating object properties and adding them in a new Arr with Reduce Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, reduce, square-bracket

I am trying to use reduce within addKeyAndValue function on an array of objects with properties of key-value pairs, add within each object a new key-value pair and return that on a new array. The addKeyAndValue func receives three arguments the arr, the key and the value to be added together within each object in the array. I then use push within Reduce callback to push the objects in the array to the new array in the accumulator with the updated new key and value using the bracket notation.

```
var arr = [{name: 'Alonso'}, {name: 'James'}, {name: 'Chris'}, {name: 'Steve'}]

function addKeyAndValue(arr, key, value){
    return arr.reduce(function(acc, nextValue, idx){
        console.log(next);
        acc.push(nextValue[key] = value);
        return acc;
    },[]);
}
```

and the expected result should be:

```
addKeyAndValue(arr, 'title', 'Instructor') // 
      [
        {title: 'Instructor', name: 'Alonso'}, 
        {title: 'Instructor', name: 'James'}, 
        {title: 'Instructor', name: 'Chris'}, 
        {title: 'Instructor', name: 'Steve'}
       ]
```

however, the results that I get in my Chrome dev console is:

```
(4) ["Instructor", "Instructor", "Instructor", "Instructor"]
0:"Instructor"
1:"Instructor"
2:"Instructor"
3:"Instructor"
length:4
__proto__:Array(0)
```

I am wondering why is the Value passed through `nextValue[key]` overriding the whole object and returning just as a string. When I try to just push the existing objects in the new array it works fine but when pushing the `nextValue[key]` it turns undefined and when doing the above `nextValue[key] = value` it overrides the objects resulting into a new array with just `instructor` strings. I am a bit confused since I was expecting a different result.

Using the bracket notations `nextValue[key]` on nextValue which is each object within the array being iterated by the callback in the reduce method I thought that would add a new key property in this case `"title"` with the assigned value of `"instructor"`.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `push` argument only results in the `value` being pushed, not the object. You can solve this with the comma operator if your really want this in one expression:

```
acc.push((nextValue[key] = value, nextValue));
```

But it may be more readable if you do it separately:

```
nextValue[key] = value;
acc.push(nextValue);
```

Comment: the first line you did didn't yield the expected resulted since it printed the the instructor together with the updated object but the second one did the job. But still wondering why the second line you shared works separately then acc.push(nextValue[key] = value); since is basically same thing to me.

Comment: Did you notive the extra parentheses? I added them seconds after I posted 

Comment: Your version does not work because you do not push the object. That assignment only gives you the assigned value, not the mutated object.

Comment: I see @trincot that seems quite a weird behavior in js, the first line that you shared was correct needed to put nextValue[key] = value, nextValue within it's own parenthesis. Any idea why need to do that? It is the first time that i see it being used like that.

Comment: The inner parentheses make the comma act as an operator instead of a function argument separator. Search comma operator.

Comment: I see that is interesting, thanks for the help. I will research it.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the result of the assignment into the array, instead of the object.

Since the result `nextValue[key] = value` is `value`. Using `acc.push(nextValue[key] = value);` is like doing `acc.push(value)`.

Since you want to update each object, [use Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the array. Clone each object (to prevent mutating the original objects) using [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), and add the property:

```js
var arr = [{name: 'Alonso'}, {name: 'James'}, {name: 'Chris'}, {name: 'Steve'}];

function addKeyAndValue(arr, key, value){
  return arr.map(function(obj){
    var clone = Object.assign({}, obj);
    clone[key] = value;
    return clone;
  });
}

var result = addKeyAndValue(arr, 'title', 'Instructor');

console.log(result);
```

**The ES6 version**

```js
const arr = [{name: 'Alonso'}, {name: 'James'}, {name: 'Chris'}, {name: 'Steve'}];

function addKeyAndValue(arr, key, value){
  return arr.map((obj) => Object.assign({ [key]: value }, obj));
}

const result = addKeyAndValue(arr, 'title', 'Instructor');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am well aware of the other array methods and I did solve this another way using reduce but I am not yet clear why the one that I shared here doesn't work. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Look at the 1st sentence. I'll add an example.

Comment: yeah i get it, but still don't know why is it happening. If you check above the code that tricont shared is exactly the same like mine but he just put nextValue[key] = value in separate line and then below acc.push(nextValue) which is working as i wanted. Yet, in that case it didn't override the object adding it within the object rather than the array.

Comment: You are changing the original object `nextValue[key] = value`, but you don't push the object, but the results of the assignment. The result is `value`. The object is changed, but not pushed into the new array. If you'll `console.log(arr)`, you'll see that the original objects were changed. In trincots answer, he assign the value to the object, then pushes the object.

Comment: Yeah, i did notice that a while ago in my console by using console.log on the arr. On the other hand is the first time that i see the method that trincot used with two parenthesis, he wrapped the nextValue[key] = value, nextValue with parenthesis and it did work properly. But i want to know the why behind since i don't want to jump again similar problems.

Comment: Because he used the comma operator, and returned the `nextValue`. However, this still changes the original object. If you don't won't to change the original object, you can clone it (see my answer).

Comment: I see, but i want to see it solve with reduce method not map, if you could provide a similar execution with reduce would be much helpful. Because i am learning Reduce and not map. Thanks